# Why command grep not working when with asterisc wildcard *

Tags: regex, bash, ubuntu, unix, grep

I have this folder:

```
Folder
    ├── stu1
    ├── foo
    └── student9
```

When I execute this command

```
ls |grep s*
```

The result is

```
student9
```

I was expecting stu1, student9

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `*` is interpreted by the shell. You can surround it with quotes in order to "shield" it from the shell and pass it down to `grep`:

```
$ ls | grep "s*"
```

Comment: I think OP is confusing glob and regex, `grep "s*"` should probably be  `grep 's'` or  `grep '^s'`